# How to clip precipitation layer to a shapefile in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, shapefile, clip, precipitation

I downloaded a 4000m resolution precipitation dataset from ClimateEngine. I tried clipping by mask layer and the clipped raster doesn’t fill out the shapefile leaving major gaps. What can be done so that the clipped raster fills out the shape of the mask layer?[image: Image of clipped layer on top of shapefile]

Comment: Hi, welcome to GIS.SE. Do you want to use the `-cblend 1` additional command line parameter? I think that it will extend the cutline by one pixel, because the polygon doesn't cover those adjacent pixels.

Comment: It looks like a pixel gets selected if the polygon covers the majority of its area. Using buffered geometries for clipping should help.